How to load raw file from private gitlab into R
I'm having trouble loading a raw private file from gitlab into R.
This code does not work:
library(httr)

url <- "https://gitlab......../-/raw/main/data.csv?private_token=........"

answer <- GET(url)

if (status_code(resposta) == 200) {
 writeBin(content(answer, "raw"), "data.csv")
 } else {
  message("Error: ", status_code(resposta))

}
I got just a dataframe with htlm info.

what does curl return ?
curl -X GET "https://gitlab........../-/raw/main/data.csv?private_toke...." -H "Accept: .csv" 

Didnt work out. Seems that curl does not work in R.

Try in console, not in R. First we try to debug are 'simple' tools work over network.

Got the message: You are being redirected.

So seems like, response is not your csv data. Fix that first, so you get csv back with curl CMD.
